# Неполное предложение

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

На сайте аск.фм. специалисты экстренной лингвистической помощи утверждают, что синтаксический разбор данного  предложения неоднозначен.

Среди легковых машин есть как большие, нарядные, так и маленькие, невзрачные.

Возможны две трактоаки. Прилагательные  выступают здесь в роли подлежашего. Но можно считать предложение неполным. А прилагательные тогда будут определением.

Вот насчет неполного немного сомневаюсь. Ведь здесь не пропущен член предложения, необходимый для полноты строения и значения данного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

*Среди легковых машин есть (**машины**) как большие, нарядные, так и маленькие, невзрачные.*

Это **неполное** предложение, так как пропущено подлежащее ***машины***.

Прилагательные со значением признака (не перешедшие в существительные) не могут выступать в роли подлежащего.

Comment: В роли подледащее может выступать любое слово. Ср: Старший учится в школе.     В нашем же примере прилагательные по смыслу связаны со сказуемым.

Comment: Я отметила в ответе: не перешедшие в существительные. Старший  -  субстантивированное прилагательное. оно даже в словаре есть Старший, -его; м. Тот, кто возглавляет какую-л. группу людей; начальник. С. конвоя. С. отделения. С. в походе. Отыскать глазами среди военных старшего. Старшая, -ей; ж. (1, 3 зн.).

Comment: В этом значении субстантивированное прилагательное?1. Имеющий большее количество лет по сравнению с кем-л., самый взрослый среди кого-л. С. сын в семье.

Comment: Старший сын - это обычное прилагательное.  У нее двое детей,  старший уже пошел в школу.  Мой старший уже учится. Это субстантивированное прилагательное, переход в существительное.

Comment: В роли подлежащего может употребятся любое прилагательное, заменяющее по смыслу имя существительное.